# Slim 3 framework group routing

Tags: php, slim

I want to use group routing in Slim 3 Framework, but I always get "Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server". I am not sure what I did wrong. Here's the code I wrote:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$app = new \Slim\App();

// API Version Group
$app->group("/v1", function() use($app) {
   $app->get("/test1", function() use($app){
       return "from v1 tes1";
   });
});

//Run the app
$app->run();

?>
```

I ran this locally like : `http://localhost/MyAPI/v1/test1`. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I've removed my answer since it didn't solve the problem. But I've created test project and your code works perfectly. So it's not directly related to this code snippet. All I did was install Slim 3 with composer, create `.htaccess` file (copied from Slim's docs) and created index.php with the same exact content as yours above.

Comment: hey it works for me too. Thanks! It's weird just putting the .htaccess solves the issue. Do you know why? @dragoste

Comment: Well, you need .htaccess to configure Apache's `mod_rewrite` module. Without it you can handle urls dynamically.

Comment: I smell a configuration issue here with your web server setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue just by adding .htaccess in the root folder.

```
#.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Thanks for everyone who helped me!